# Tomcat integrated in Eclipse starts in normal mode, but fails to start in debug mode (on CentOS platform)

Tags: eclipse, debugging, centos, tomcat6

I'm using tomcat 6 integrated with eclipse (kepler) on centOS platform. When I start tomcat on normal mode, it works fine but when I try to start it in debug mode, it fails to start.
It gives the error "Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost failed to start."
Has anyone faced this problem before? Any suggeastions ?